# How to create a borderless window with titlebar in windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, direct3d

I am trying to create a Direct3D app that is operating in windowed mode with a title bar and minimize/quit button. However, I'd really like to be able to axe the border around the window.

I am looking to do this because it looks pretty cheesy on dual monitors when the app is filling the primary monitor horizontally (with room to move the app vertically), but its window border overflows onto the secondary screen.  I've tried a bunch of combinations of `setwindowlong` with `GWL_STYLE` and `GWL_EXSTYLE`, but can't seem to make headway unless I disable the title bar.

I've seen a bunch of apps that are borderless however they seem to emulate the title bar rather than using the built in one provided by Microsoft.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So you already know "how the experts do it". What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Basically, the idea is to draw your own titlebar on a borderless window, then listen for mouse events and move/minimize/close when an appropriate event happens. This means you'd just use the bare window type (no title bar/borders).

Comment: The question is asking if there is a way to do it using the built in windows titlebar..  ie to have a titlebar but with no border outside the client area.

Comment: [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx): *"**WS_CAPTION**: The window has a title bar (includes the **WS_BORDER** style)."* In other words, you cannot have a title bar without having a border as well. You'll have to implement your own title bar.

Comment: Is omitting `WS_THICKFRAME` insufficient? Note that doing so makes your window nonresizeable.

Comment: andlabs - omitting ws_thickframe is the look I want, but with a caption still.

Comment: llnspectable - even though the docs say that ws_caption forces ws_border, the weird thing is if you specificy only ws_border the window looks the way I would expect with a thin black line border. if you say only ws_thickframe looks exactly like the ws_caption border, it almost feels like an error in the docs.

Comment: SetWindowRgn seems to do what I want, as in it clips the window to whatever area I want preventing the borders from drawing, however it corrupts the window style so the title bar looks like im back in windows 98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't remove the border and keep the titlebar AFAIK.**

You can reimplement the titlebar by using `WM_NCHITTEST` but you still need to draw it yourself which would not be a bad idea if you want your D3D app to look its best.

Visual Studio, last time I checked, achieves its border with transparent layered windows standing behind the primary one. They are the shadows you see.